# How to add an existing create-react-app to an existing solution in visual studio 2019?

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio

I have a create-react-app, and I have as a backend a few .net projects in visual studio, and I want to connect my react app to be under the same solution in visual studio.
I tried adding it to solution as: add existing web site, and by me it works fine.
But when I add it to git you can't open it on another computer.
Maybe something I'm doing wrong or is there another way to do it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was that I created a separate react app, not connected to .net C# project that sends rest APi calls to my C# .net backend.
I saw you can't add it as an item in the solution.